# how to track Google Analytics of Adobe Air app?

Tags: google-analytics, air

I have written an Adobe Air desktop application that tracks a bunch of websites and displays images from the websites in the app. And instead of keeping my mouth shut about it and making it look like an attack on the website, I'd like to make it so that the webmasters can see that these pageviews are made by my application.

Is there any way the webmaster could distinguish adobe air access of the website from normal visitor browsing? Perhaps by adding something to the URLrequests I make in the application..?

Comment: candidate for webmasters@stackexchange?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Google Analytics to Adobe Air HTML/Javascript App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914839/adding-google-analytics-to-adobe-air-html-javascript-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics captures browser settings. Make your app pass a unique user-agent, thus any visit with your app could be separated from everything else.